# How to Delete Specific Multi Records in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, delete-row

I want to delete 4,6,8,11,12 records by using model at a time. I also want to know how to do it without deleting the following records 3,5,6,7 by using model.

**Controller Function**

```
public function delete_data($id,$value){
    $oris = explode("_", $value);
    $oris = array_filter($oris);
    $this->o->delete_data($oris);
}
```

**Model Function**

```
public function delete_data($id){
    $this->db->where('campus_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('sections');
}
```

Comment: please show us some effort on what you already tried... ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4,6,8,11,12 records Deleted

```
public function delete_data($id){
    $this->db->where_in('campus_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('sections');
}
```

3,5,6,7 records not Deleted

```
public function delete_data($id){
    $this->db->where_not_in('campus_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('sections');
}
```

Wow I Got It..

Answer (score 1):

YOUR MODEL

```
public function delete_record() //You can pass ID as a parameter here
{
    $this->db->where('column-name', 'your-id'); //id can be 4, 6, 8, 11, 12
    return $this->db->delete('table-name');
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother :) you solved my problem ...

Comment: @AliHaider if worked accept answer